# SELECT dependientes de 2 niveles con SELECT2

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo 2 select(combos) donde ocupo que al seleccionar un elemento del primer select llamémoslo "select1" en el segundo select llamémoslo "select2" solo sea elegible información dependiendo de lo elegido en el "select1"

Especificando un poco. Tengo el select "Tipo Costo" y "Costo" 
Cuando seleccione, por ejemplo tipo costo= Demoras, del select "Tipo Costo" en el select "Costo" solo se listen los costos de ese tipo. 
Esto con el "método" de javascript select2

Código de los select:

```
<td>
                    <select class="tipoCostos form-control" name="tipoCostos" id="tipoCostos" required>
                        <option value="">Tipo Costo</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td>
                    <select class="costos form-control" name="costos" id="costos" required>
                        <option value="">Costos</option>
                    </select>
                            </td>
```

Cargador de los tipos de costo:

```
<?php
// connect to database
include("../config/db.php");        
 $con=@mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$search = strip_tags(trim($_GET['q'])); 
// Do Prepared Query
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tipoCostos WHERE tipoCosto LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT 40");
// Do a quick fetchall on the results
$list = array();
while ($list=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $data[] = array('id' => $list['id'], 'text' => $list['tipoCosto']);
}
// return the result in json
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Llamando el método de los select

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".tipoCostos" ).select2({        
    ajax: {
        url: "ajax/load_tipoCostos.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term // search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".costos" ).select2({        
    ajax: {
        url: "ajax/load_costos.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term // search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
});
</script>
```

No tengo idea de cómo realizar esto que necesito, mi pregunta es ¿cómo realizar esto?

Comment: La tabla costos tiene la relación con la tabla tipo_costo?

Comment: Exactamente. Costos tiene una fk "tipoCosto"

Answer (score 0):

trataré de usar tu código para explicarte como puedes hacer lo que necesitas.

1. Debes enviar el id del tipo_costo

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $( ".costos" ).select2({        
       ajax: {
           url: "ajax/load_costos.php",
           dataType: 'json',
           delay: 250,
           data: function (params) {
               return {
                   q: params.term, // search term
                   id: $("#tipoCostos").val() // id seleccionado del select2 tipo_costo 
               };
           },
           processResults: function (data) {
               return {
                   results: data
               };
           },
           cache: true
       }
   });
   });
   </script>
   ```
2. en tu clase de php (no se nada de php) debes consultar con ese ID

   ```
   <?php
   // connect to database
       include("../config/db.php");        
        $con=@mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
       $search = strip_tags(trim($_GET['q'])); 
       $id_tc= strip_tags(trim($_GET['id'])); 
       // Do Prepared Query
       $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM costos WHERE idTipoCosto = '$id_tc' AND nameCosto LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT 40");
       // Do a quick fetchall on the results
       $list = array();
       while ($list=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
           $data[] = array('id' => $list['id'], 'text' => $list['nameCosto']);
       }
       // return the result in json
       echo json_encode($data);
   ?>
   ```